# Could we add a description field in the image uploader?

Tags: feature-request, design, images, markdown

When we add an image to a post, the resulting markdown is:

```
![enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ySkR.png
```

And in order to add a tooltip, you'll need to do this:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ySkR.png "tooltip"
```

Very easy to do, but I most images I see on Programmers have neither a description nor a tooltip, I guess people don't care much to add any more information after the image is uploaded. I think it would be far more easier if the image dialog had an extra field for description:

[image: Venn diagram from FAQ]

And the resulting markdown would be:

```
![Venn diagram from FAQ][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ociNc.png
```

Comment: That's a good idea. The tooltip field would have to be optional though, or pre-filled with the default "enter image description here", from a UX perspective I don't think it would be nice if we forced people to write a description and we would end up with most people adding garbage there just to get by it.

Answer (score 7):

I like this idea but the `title` attribute really shouldn't be set identically to the `alt` attribute. Just for accessibility reasons I'd support leaving the alt text box there but I'm not sure how much value the tooltip provides; you should be explaining the reason for the image in your body copy anyway, so tooltips shouldn't be as necessary.

Agree with Yannis as well that it should be optional, maybe "enter a description here" in *placeholder text*. I'm not convinced a billion images with alt text of "enter a description here" is good either... (and yes, that's what alt text is set to and what screen readers announce if you leave the default text at the moment).

Comment: I've removed the tooltip from the question, you're right, I never thought of this from an accessibility pov.